# Bits Not Shifting

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I want to be able to create a shift from right to left everytime I press a button, but my simulation says my bits is not shifting.

this is the code I wrote:

```
module Sipo(KEY0, qIN, qOUT, LEDsipo);
    input KEY0;
    output reg [5:0] qIN;
    output reg [5:0] qOUT;
    output [6:0] LEDsipo;
        
        assign LEDsipo[0] = qIN[0];
        assign LEDsipo[1] = qIN[1];
        assign LEDsipo[2] = qIN[2];
        assign LEDsipo[3] = qIN[3];
        assign LEDsipo[4] = qIN[4];
        assign LEDsipo[5] = qIN[5];
        assign LEDsipo[6] = KEY0;
    
    always @(KEY0) begin
    if (KEY0 == 1)
        qIN = 6'b000000;
        qOUT[0] <= KEY0;
        qOUT[1] <= qOUT[0];
        qOUT[2] <= qOUT[1];
        qOUT[3] <= qOUT[2];
        qOUT[4] <= qOUT[3];
        qOUT[5] <= qOUT[4];
        if (qOUT == 7'b111111)
            qOUT[0] = 0;
            qOUT[1] = 0;
            qOUT[2] = 0;
            qOUT[3] = 0;
            qOUT[4] = 0;
            qOUT[5] = 0;
    qIN = qOUT;
    end
        
endmodule
```

The result I got in the simulation is that LEDsipo[0] was responding to KEY0, but the rest of the LEDsipo was not. I don't see why my bits are not shifting.

Answer (score 0):

It is dificult to test your code without a testbench, which you have not provided, but I thik that you rissue is an extra exposure to python.

Verilog does not understand indentation as scope indicators and requires `begin`/`end` to indicats scopes. So, my guess is that you have at least several issues:

1. missing begin/end: `if (KEY0 == 1) begin...end`
2. incorrect mix of non-blocing/non-blocking assignments mix
3. Incorrect coding of your latch
4. bad use of veriog syntax

so, though it is corret, you can avoid using separate bits:

```
   assign LEDsipo[6:0] = {KEY0, qIN[5:0]};
```

do not use sensititivity lists in the latch, it will not synthesize correctly in your case. Use `always @*` instead. Well, and begin/end.
I do not know why you need qIn, but it makes no sense to initialize it to 0 in the first place. Also, it is not a part of the latch and should be moved out of the always block.

```
always @* begin
   if (KEY0 == 1) begin // need begin/end for multiple statements
      // qIN <= 6'b000000; -- why do you need it?
      qOut[5:0] <= {qOut[4:0], KEY0};
      if (qOUT == 7'b111111) // can omit begin/end for a single statement
           qOut <= 6'b0;
   end
end

assign qIn = qOut;
```

Since you have not provide any testbench,  I did not test the code.

Comment: Thank you Serge I've made some edits to the code, the code does shift, but it doesn't shift the way I expected it to. It goes from ```0000000``` to ```1111111``` . 
The editions I've made is turning qIN and qOUT to simply q,  and giving it ```[7:0]``` instead of ```[5:0]``` .
I've wanted to use qIN and qOUT because before I've added qIN and qOUT it was just q, when I initiated q with ```6'b000000``` and made the code shift it I wanted the new shift bits to be the new q and not the initiation. 
 I didn't provide a testbench, because I don't know what it is. Is the simulation the testbench?

Comment: testbench is just a code whch tests your design in smulation. It provides input data (stimulus) and checks correctness of the simulation results.